# How to set selinux file permissions on specific files?

Tags: permissions, selinux

I have a couple of files that I copied from one device to another and it's causing problems because the file permissions need to be changed.

What I'm getting:

```
$ ls -laZ
...
drwxrwx--x   2 u0_a119 u0_a119       u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c119,c256,c512,c768  4096 2019-07-21 08:25 databases
```

What I need:

```
drwxrwx--x   2 u0_a215 u0_a215       u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c215,c256,c512,c768   4096 2019-07-21 08:25 databases
```

The basic file permissions are fine and changing ownership with `chown u0_a215:u0_a215 databases` would be easy. But how do  I change the `u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c215,c256,c512,c768` thing?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a Multi-Category Security (MCS) SELinux policy.
If so, then those categories might have human-readable descriptions defined in `/etc/selinux/targeted/setrans.conf`. The list of category descriptions could also be viewed with `chcat -L`.

I don't know how the categories are defined at your site, and it's probably best it stays that way. But changing the `c119` to `c215` might mean something like changing something that is marked as "payroll information" to "medical information". So it is an operation that requires privileges appropriate for accessing both categories.

The command to change the categories would be:

```
chcat -- +c215 -c119 databases
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very valuable information. `chcat` or `/etc/selinux/targeted/setrans.conf` don't exist on that device unfortunately. I do have `/etc/selinux` though and at least `setenforce` , `secilc` and `restorecon` (which seems like black magic) do exist. The device I'm working with is an Android device btw in case that's relevant.